# can we print data to a file with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, save

I'm learning to code and I'm building an app to create characters for a role playing game. I need you thaughts on something... I use html, css and Js. I'm trying toget good at these three ... It wont be online, but it'smeant to run in a browser.

For now, I work with an object called 'player'. As the person makes choices and dice roles, I update this object to keep track of the character's stats... player.force, player.origins, player.skills, etc...
I don't know if I'm on the good path or if I should find another way of saving the data. Should I print the data to a file everytime the play object is updated? Is that a thing in JS? I'm thinkin about this because I think I will have to load new pages now and then and I don't know If I can carry the data stored in the JS file to the next page. And if for some reason the browser gets shut down, it would be nice if we could reload the already made stats.

hope you guys understant my interrogations... and that you can advise me on it..

thanks in advance!

Eric

Comment: Web pages cannot directly edit files on a person's computer. That would obviously be a big breach of security. There are some experimental APIs for this, but its beyond the scope. If you want to make a program in javascript that can edit files. You can use nodejs.

Comment: You can use some sort of cookie, otherwise, as @John stated, you cannot arbitarily edit files on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

There are few alternatives:

1. You can run node server, or bundle browser and node in Electron app to access files and persistent storage.
2. You can store it to browser locally, eg using localStorage api

   localStorage.setItem('myHealth', '1');
   let myHealth = Number(localStorage.getItem('myHealth'));

Local storage persists even if you close the browser or visit other pages of the domain.

Read more from here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

3. Lastly, you can use some simple online service that let's you persist the data, for example firebase.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that browser can't write to filesystem. But can it do it if it only reads local files? My app will not be online.. Or could the stats be stored in a cookie?

Comment: No, you'd need something like Electron or server to write local files too.
But you can use local storage, similary to cookies.